# Win32 API Find the MDI Client Handle from the Parent Window Handle

Tags: windows, winapi, pyqt5, mdi, mdichild

I have a MDI application at hand named "MDI demo". I want to take a snapshot of one of its sub-window with the win32 API, say "subwindow1". I can get the parent main window of the application with `GetApplicationHwnd`. But I don't find any API to get the direct child MDI client window.

Currently, I tried the EnumChildWindow with the handle to parent as the argument. However, it seems no child window found in the MDI application.

Here is an example, the MDI application is in Python, PyQt5

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   count = 0

   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
      self.mdi = QMdiArea()
      self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
      bar = self.menuBar()

      file = bar.addMenu("File")
      file.addAction("New")
      file.addAction("cascade")
      file.addAction("Tiled")
      file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)
      self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

   def windowaction(self, q):
      print "triggered"

      if q.text() == "New":
         MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count+1
         sub = QMdiSubWindow()
         sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
         sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow"+str(MainWindow.count))
         self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
         sub.show()

      if q.text() == "cascade":
         self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()

      if q.text() == "Tiled":
         self.mdi.tileSubWindows()

def main():
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = MainWindow()
  ex.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

And the skeleton of my win32 snapshot program in C++ is as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    cout << "I find a child" << endl;
}

char APPNAME[] = "MDI demo";
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<HWND> hwnds = GetApplicationHwnd(APPNAME);
    int succeed = 0;
    cout << "Found " << hwnds.size() << " windows called " << APPNAME << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < hwnds.size(); ++i) {
        EnumChildWindows(hwnds[i], EnumChildProc, (LPARAM)NULL);
    }
    int a;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Would you mind any hint how to proceeds? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to enumerate MDI child windows in a Qt application? I'm not sure Qt would actually create native child windows in an MDI application. At least not in any application using Qt version 4 or later.

Comment: @linspectable Yes, I need to iterate through children of a Qt application.

Comment: Qt doesn't use native `HWND`s. If you are lucky, Qt supports [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) well enough, so that you can query the MDI child window size and position, and take it from there.

Comment: There is an extra level of indirection.  The main window has an MDICLIENT window, the one with the dark grey background.  *That* window owns the child windows.  A utility like Spy++ is useful to see this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, Hans. Very useful tips. However, why no child window enumerated? It is really strange.

Comment: Qt doesn't use native windows for MDI children. A Qt application is a single window, with all widgets rendered into it. The only time when Qt allocates a new native window is for owned windows (dialogs, the dropdown list of a combo box, etc.). That's why `EnumChildWindows` returns nothing for just about any Qt application. You can use Spy++ to verify this.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for your comments. All correctly re-produced on my side. I'm now try another way to solve the problem (pixel matching at present).

Comment: Pixel matching is the very last thing you should consider doing. UI Automation is way more robust (if it is supported in your scenario).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. I'm not sure the application I'm now trying to capturing supports the UI Automation well. But anyway, I will give the UI Automation a try. Appreciate your help a lot and happy new year. :)

Comment: To quickly verify, whether your target application implements the required UI Automation interfaces for the items you are interested in, use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521.aspx) tool, that ships with the Windows SDK.